# Attach custom gallery to a page

Tags: gallery

I am developing my first WordPress website and am trying to find a way to do the following. Website editor needs to be able to create image gallery pages by attaching multiple images with metadata when creating a new page. For each gallery image there are full size and thumbnail images as well as image description. I would like to use some plugin similar to NextGen gallery to manage picture libraries in Wordpress but i don't want this plugin to actually display any pictures - I have a custom made jQuery gallery for this. My html code will have to be produced by a custom page template.

So, I am looking for either a plugin which would allow me to "attach" grouped custom fields to a page (images or image URLs and descriptions), or may be a direction how to customize a plugin like NextGen Gallery so that it didn't add any of it's code to my pages.

Also, possibly please consider that I am not a PHP dev and I won't be able to do difficult code customizations without good guidance.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload images in media of each page by using INSER GALLERY button.You can Upload multiple images & galleries also.

You can get all images of each page by using below code.

```
$images = get_posts(
    array(
         'numberposts' => -1,
         'post_parent' => $post->ID,
         'post_status' => 'inherit',
         'post_type' => 'attachment',
         'post_mime_type' => 'image',
         'order' => 'ASC',
         'orderby' => 'menu_order'
         )
);
```